# Frequency transported via electric cable

Tags: power

Newbie here, a (home-made) computer technician.

So here is my question, frequency (megahertz) is not electric? But sound waves? Is this correct? A close friend, an electrical engineer, explained to me that broadband megahertz was a type of audio, and is transported through electric cabling on the outer of the cable? i.e. he said that the broadband (term) is sent by module, spiraling constantly and is received after many relays at the other end by another module. i.e. modem/router, or other device. Is this accurate? This is laymans terms, he said it is megahertz and should not be confused with electric, which in general is measured by amperes, voltage and ohms, and of course the usage in watts or kilowatts.

The basic question: Frequency is or is not electric?

Comment: frequency is a measurement of cyclic-change. It can be applied to anything: electricity, electromagnetic radiation (light, radio), sound, water tides or waves, planets, microprocessor clock frequency. It makes just as much sense to measure the frequency of something as it does to measure the mass of potatoes, cheese, people, water, planets. I found your question very confusing. You seem to be mashing independent things together.

Comment: Maybe your friend was talking about broadband internet connection over old telephone lines, which were designed to carry sound (converted to electric signal).

Comment: venny your bang on, so if you understood the question, peter explained it to me correctly, its a broadband connected thru bt phoneline,accepted

Answer (score 4):

Frequency is just how often something happens. It may be electrical in nature, or how often your local police officer visits the bakery for a doughnut.

> "The square wave is 42 kHz."

This would most likely be someone describing an electrical signal, saying that it happens 42 thousand times per second.

> "That tone is over a thousand cycles per second."

This would be describing sound, waves of air pressure.

> "He gets a doughnut about once a week."

And this is describing the frequency with which someone does a particular thing.

In both audio and electrical applications, frequency is usually measured in [Hertz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertz) which means "times per second." The SI prefixes such as *kilo*, *mega*, and *giga* can be applied to multiply by one thousand, one million, or one billion, respectively.

So, ***no***, frequency is not always electrical in nature.

Answer (score 2):

Frequency' is independent of what is oscillating. It could be sound, radio waves, mechanical vibrations of a tuning fork, a child's swing, how often you go to the bathroom, whatever.

In the case of AC it's how frequently the electricity switches polarity. Ordinary "120 VAC 60Hz" power switches back and forth between polarities 60 times per second.

Comment: +1 for making me think of one's bathroom frequency in Hz.

Comment: much appreciated